# How is [NSDate date] calculated?

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsdate

I'm using part of the current date in a scheme on a web server and I want to generate the same value on the device as on the server. In theory I thought about a case where these two values wouldn't be the same and the values on either end wouldn't match.

Which then led me to think - how, *specifically*, is `[NSDate date]` calculated when an app is running?

**Edit:** I guess what I'm really asking, is **how does an iPhone get its time from an authoritative source?** It appears it comes from a cell tower which I would assume are all synced somehow. Is this true?

**Edit:** Looks like it uses gettimeofday() which uses the system clock. And from [Apple docs](http://support.apple.com/kb/ta38641), looks like when you have the iPhone set to 'Set Automatically', it uses the correct time over the cell network.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean, how is it calculated? It returns the current date according to the device clock. And no, there's no reason to expect this is going to be precisely equal to the time according to the server.

Comment: The device clock is what I think I'm looking for. How is the device clock set?

Comment: He's asking "What's the beginning of the epoch?"

Comment: The only way to make sure your server and device have the same time is to send the time data from the server to the device.  The clock is set either by the user or by the system when it asks for the current time from the nearest cell tower (if on a cell phone/3g ipad).  It might also be set by itunes on sync but i don't know for sure.

Comment: @barfoon: Can you clarify? We're a bit confused.

Comment: I'm asking - when [NSDate date] is called, where does it go to get its values? Looks like it uses gettimeofday() - where does that method get its values?

Comment: I guess what I'm REALLY looking to find out, is how does an iPhone device get its time from an authoritative source. Seems like the cell tower - which I would assume are all synchronized via some means.

Comment: Great question, and something that I wonder, too.  For example, if I set my Mac to get its time automatically from the network and my iPhone to get its time automatically from "Set Automatically" method, I get different times, sometimes as much as two minutes apart(!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can find out by stepping through in the debugger or simply sample it for the callstacks.

it uses `gettimeofday`.

as such, you can't expect this value to be equal or perfectly synchronized on two devices.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that your app may run on an iPod Touch, or on a phone that simply has no 3G connection.  You get whatever time the phone is displaying on its top bar.

Answer (score 1):

UNIX system clock, using (as other people said) `gettimeofday()`. Phone probably synchronizes with an NTP server such as `time.apple.com` - this is what desktop OS X does.